# Using BLAME command of SVN from within XCODE

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, svn

When we integrate SVN with XCODE, how can I use blame command from within XCODE. I did not see any option there.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4:

File Menu -> Open... (Select the file you wish to examine).

View Menu -> Version Editor -> Show Blame View

Comment: So, how do you hide it? There is no "Hide blame view" and the show command doesn't toggle it...

Comment: View -> Standard Editor -> Show Standard Editor

Answer (score 0):

Xcode menu - SCM - Get Annotations For - ...

Comment: Why all options under this path are disabled for me?

Comment: Did you select some file(s) in project navigator before going to SCM menu?